# Passing javascript variables into attribute of html object

Tags: javascript, html

I cannot figure out how to pass variables (p1,p2,p3) into the 'data-url' attribute of this html object, an embedded typeform. I'm getting an error of invalid left hand assignment when using "a.url-data" and was getting an undefined function when using a.setAttribute("url-data", "http.....)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
   if (!url) url = window.location.href;
   name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
   var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
   results = regex.exec(url);
   if (!results) return null;
   if (!results[2]) return '';
   console.log('The value of ' + name + ' is: ' + results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
   return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, "%20"));
}

var p1 = getParameterByName('p1')
var p2 = getParameterByName('p2')
var p3 = getParameterByName('p3')

p1 = p1.replace(/ /g, "%20");
p2 = p2.replace(/ /g, "%20");
p3 = p3.replace(/ /g, "%20");
// ]]></script><!-- Change the width and height values to suit you best -->
<div class="typeform-widget" data-url="https://eatforklore.typeform.com/to/XPDPsx?p1=xxxxx&amp;p2=xxxxx&amp;p3=xxxxx&amp;p4=xxxxx" data-text="Mo. 1 Product Reviews" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
<script>// <![CDATA[
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('typeform-widget');
a.data-url = "https://eatforklore.typeform.com/to/XPDPsx?p1=" + p1;

(function(){var qs,js,q,s,d=document,gi=d.getElementById,ce=d.createElement,gt=d.getElementsByTagName,id='typef_orm',b='https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/share.typeform.com/';if(!gi.call(d,id)){js=ce.call(d,'script');js.id=id;js.src=b+'widget.js';q=gt.call(d,'script')[0];q.parentNode.insertBefore(js,q)}})()
// ]]></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, the script is running before the `div` with the class name exists. You need to do this:

```
    <div class="typeform-widget" data-url="https://eatforklore.typeform.com/to/XPDPsx?p1=xxxxx&amp;p2=xxxxx&amp;p3=xxxxx&amp;p4=xxxxx" data-text="Mo. 1 Product Reviews" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var a = document.getElementsByTagName('typeform-widget');
        a.setAttribute('data-url', "https://eatforklore.typeform.com/to/XPDPsx?p1=" +p1);
    </script>
```

Comment: Also there's no such thing as `window.getElementsByClassName`, and `document.getElementsByClassName` returns multiple elements, so calling `setAttribute` on its return value won't work...

Comment: yes, set attribute does not work so I've changed to: